# Raw (binary) data too big to write to disk. How to write chunk-wise to disk (appending)?

Tags: r, memory, binary, large-files

I have a large raw vector in R (i.e. array of binary data) that I want to write to disk, but I'm getting an error telling me the vector is too large. Here's a reproducible example and the error I get:

```
> writeBin(raw(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2), "test.bin")

Error in writeBin(raw(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2), "test.bin") : 
  long vectors not supported yet: connections.c:4147
```

I've noticed that this is linked to the 2 GB file limit. If I try to write a single byte less (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 - 1), it works just fine.

I was thinking about doing some kind of workaround, where I write chunks of the large file to disk in batches, only appending the binary data to the disk, like this:

```
large_file = raw(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2) 
chunk_size = 1024*1024*512
n_chunks = ceiling(length(large_file)/chunk_size)

for (i in 1:n_chunks)
{
  start_byte = ((i - 1) * chunk_size) + 1
  end_byte = start_byte + chunk_size - 1
  if (i == n_chunks)
    end_byte = length(large_file)
  this_chunk = large_file[start_byte:end_byte]
  appendBin(this_chunk, "test.bin") # <-- non-existing magical formula!
}
```

But I can't find any kind of function like the "appendBin" I wrote above or any other documentation in R that tells me how to append data straight to the disk.

So my question boils down to this: does anyone know how to **append** raw (binary) data to a file **already on** disk without having to read the full file on disk to memory first?

Extra details: I'm currently using R version 3.4.2 64bit on a Windows 10 PC with 192GB of RAM. I tried on another PC (R version 3.5 64bit, Windows 8 with 8GB of RAM) and had the exact same problem.

Any kind of insight or workaround would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with a file system 2 GB limit, it has to do with the limit of many functions within R to work on vectors of at most 2 GB of elements.  (Longer vectors are called `long vectors`, but apparently `writeBin` doesn't support them.)  @MichaelChirico's suggestion to use a connection opened in append mode is good, but do use mode "ab", so the data isn't interpreted as text data, with line endings messed up.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both your comments helped a lot! I'll post the final solution below. Thanks again!

Comment: maybe able to work with a connection at mode a? http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/connections.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelChirico and @user2554330, I was able to figure out a work around. Essentially, I just need to open the file in "a+b" mode as a new connection and feed **that file connection** into the writeBin function.

Here's a copy of the working code.

```
large_file = raw(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 3) 
chunk_size = 1024*1024*512
n_chunks = ceiling(length(large_file)/chunk_size)

if (file.exists("test.bin"))
  file.remove("test.bin")

for (i in 1:n_chunks)
{
  start_byte = ((i - 1) * chunk_size) + 1
  end_byte = start_byte + chunk_size - 1
  if (i == n_chunks)
    end_byte = length(large_file)
  this_chunk = large_file[start_byte:end_byte]
  output_file = file(description="test.bin",open="a+b")
  writeBin(this_chunk, output_file)
  close(output_file)
}
```

I know it's ugly that I'm opening and closing the file multiple times, but that kept the error from popping up with even bigger files.

Thanks again for the insights, guys! =)

Comment: just a suggestion i think it would be cleaner to use a while loop here, no need to calculate the number of chunks up front just go until end_byte > length(large_file)

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! I thought that if I did that, it would force me to write to disk for every single byte, making the code run slower than if I did it in chunks. I'll test it out and see what happens. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am trying to borrow this answer for github.com/richfitz/storr/issues/107 (related: github.com/richfitz/storr/issues/107 and github.com/richfitz/storr/issues/103#issuecomment-502097274). Slicing (large_file[start_byte:end_byte]) is a bottleneck. Benchmarks forthcoming.

Comment: Benchmarks: https://github.com/richfitz/storr/issues/107#issuecomment-502318772. For now, I think we need to find a good chunk size, which I suspect will be smaller than 2^20.